# Can I use an external database table for the login process in Django?

Tags: python, mysql, django

So I'm starting a new Django project that essentially requires the login & registration process be routed through an EXTERNAL & ALREADY created database.

Is it possible to have the User model use an EXTERNAL database table ONLY when Django is:

1. Logging in a user, to check if the login is valid
2. Registering a user, inserting data for that user in the external database

I would like for the rest of the Django server to use a local database.

If so, could someone either provide examples or guide me to documentation on the subject?

Comment: the answer to all of that is yes.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to use multiple database with Django is to use a database routing. By default Django stick to single database, however, if you want to implement more interesting database routing system, you can define and install your own database routers.

Database routers are installed using the DATABASE_ROUTERS setting. You have to specify this setting in your settings.py file

What you have to do is write one AuthRouter as described Django documentation [Django Multiple Database](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/multi-db/#database-routers)

Answer (score 0):

"Yes, but"

What you are looking for in the docs is called "[database router](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/multi-db/#using-routers)".
There is even an example for the auth app in the docs there.

But, there is s serious drawback to consider with this approach:

We cannot have cross-database relationships in the models. If auth tables are in a separate database, this means that any otehr app that needs a foreign key to User model is going to run into problems. You might be able to "fake" the relationships using a db that doesn't enforce relationship checks (SQLite or MyISAM/MySQL).

Out of the box, such apps are: session, authtoken, and admin (and probably more).

Alternatively, a single-sign-on solution might do a better job: django-sso, or django-mama-cas + django-cas-ng, or the commercial Stormpath.